# Uninitialised value in cmp function qsort

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, profiling, valgrind

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with this code:

```
int myCompare( const void * v1, const void * v2 ){
   const int * f1 = static_cast<const int *>(v1);
   const int * f2 = static_cast<const int *>(v2);
   if( f1[ 0 ] < f2[ 0 ] ) return -1;
   if( f1[ 0 ] > f2[ 0 ] ) return +1;
   return 0;
}
```

This is a comparator function for qsort it work's fine but when I've profiled it with valgrind I have this message in this strings  **Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)**

```
 if( f1[ 0 ] < f2[ 0 ] ) return -1;
 if( f1[ 0 ] > f2[ 0 ] ) return +1;
```

qsort is calling from [here](https://github.com/openworm/sibernetic/blob/development/src/owOpenCLSolver.cpp#L473)

valgrind output

```
==25053== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25053==    at 0x66474CB: msort_with_tmp.part.0 (msort.c:83)
==25053==    by 0x6647221: msort_with_tmp.part.0 (msort.c:45)
==25053==    by 0x6647221: msort_with_tmp.part.0 (msort.c:45)
==25053==    by 0x664777B: qsort_r (msort.c:45)
==25053==    by 0x40D002: owOpenCLSolver::_runSort(owConfigProrerty*)(owOpenCLSolver.cpp:473)
==25053==    by 0x4114DB: owPhysicsFluidSimulator::simulationStep(bool) (owPhysicsFluidSimulator.cpp:186)
==25053==    by 0x412FBC: run(int, char**, bool) (owWorldSimulation.cpp:919)
==25053==    by 0x4058D4: main (main.cpp:95)
==25053==  Uninitialised value was created by a client request
==25053==    at 0xA6AF9F8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA69BF40: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA3DCB0F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA42DECA: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA37E03F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA3558D0: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)enter code here
==25053==    by 0xA35A1C1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA35A2EC: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA32972D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA2D095E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0xA337AEB: ??? (in /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==25053==    by 0x6BDD181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
```

**UPDATE**

Actually In class owOpenCLSolver where I'm using this sort function I have no one places where buffer _particleIndex(buffer which will be sort than) is initializing explicitly but initialization is going in function [copy_buffer_from_device](https://github.com/openworm/sibernetic/blob/development/src/owOpenCLSolver.cpp#L470) which is copying data from OpenCL device into a host programm buffer. So may be the problem is in that valgrind doesn't think that _particleIndex isn't init when function is using it.

Comment: Why are you using `qsort` at first place instead of `std::sort`?

Comment: Did you ensure, that this function isn't called with uninitialized parameters?

Comment: @MohitJain I'm trying to sort array and as I see std::sort works with iterator as I see. Actually I didn't  consider std::sort, so I can't tell you why:). But thanks for information I'll take a look on it more precisely

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I'm not sure and I only can judge assuming that code works fine

Comment: @segevara `int arr1[] = {4, 1, 3, 2}; std::sort(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1));` or `int arr1[] = {4, 1, 3, 2}; std::sort(&arr1[0], &arr1[4]);`

Comment: @MohitJain thanks good to know but in my case I need sort array by two element I mean next: particleIndex list contains for every particle information about current
cell in which it contains in format {cell_id, partcile_id}. Before sorting
particleIndex list arranged by particle id. This method sort particleIndex
in accordance with order of cell.
**EXAMPLE:** `before sorting [[3,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,3],..]
           after sorting  [[1,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,0],..]`

Comment: @segevara Simple use array of `std::pair` and sort it using `std::sort`

Comment: Do you get the same warning if you replace `static_cast` with `reinterpret_cast` or c style cast?

Comment: Yes looks like the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind traces memory reads and writes and I think here it's telling you that the function happened to be called with at least one pointer to memory that's never been written to, as of the moment of the call.